# Computed property is not defined on the instance but reference during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, syntax-error, computed-properties

**Background:**

I have a child component that receives an array called `expenseButton` as props. Within the array are objects with values which I am trying to get the sum of using `array.reduce()`

**Problem**

When I use methods  to get the sum of the values it works perfectly fine but when I try to make it a computed property I get an error that states:

("test" is the name of the computed property)

**Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render**

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    expenseButton: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chosenExpenseId: null
    };
  },
    computed: {
      test() {
        return this.expenseButton.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc += curr.expensesValue;
          return acc;
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
<div>
<div class="yourBalance">
      Your monthly balance
      <br />
      <span>${{ test }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<template>
```

**UPDATE**

*The "expenseValue" property within the "expenseButton" array is coming from a database on the backend using axios*

Parent component

```
<template>
<div>
   <expense-button :myExpense="myExpense" :expenseButton="expenseButton"></expense-button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Expenses from "../components/expenses.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  components: {
    "expense-button": Expenses
  },
  data() {
    return {
      budgetOwner: "",
      myExpense: [],
      expenseButton: [],
      component: "",
      errored: false
    };
  },
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    axios
      .get("/api/budget", {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(res => {
        next(vm => {
          if (res.data.budget.length > 0) {
            vm.myExpense = res.data.budget;
            vm.expenseButton = res.data.budget[0].expenses;
          } 
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        next(vm => {
          console.log(err.response);
          vm.errored = true;
        });
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

Data from database

```
"budget":[{"expenses":[

{"expensesKey":"a","expensesValue":1,"subExpenses":"","newValue":""},

{"expensesKey":"b","expensesValue":2,"subExpenses":"","newValue":""},

{"expensesKey":"c","expensesValue":3,"subExpenses":"","newValue":""}

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
test() {
    if(this.expenseButton){
        return this.expenseButton.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc += curr.expensesValue;
          return acc;
        }, 0);
      }
    else{
        return ''
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't make a difference.  I think problem has to due with Vue not finding "test"

Comment: You added extra '}', sorry for late reply.

Comment: <script>
export default {
  props: {
    expenseButton: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chosenExpenseId: null
    };
  },
    computed: {
      test() {
        return this.expenseButton.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc += curr.expensesValue;
          return acc;
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
</script>

replace this code

Answer (score 0):

Try to help you. The problem will be in `curr.expensesValue`. What is expensesValue? And one more question. Are you mount right your app? Are you have the same id in the root like a `el:'#app'` and div#id in my example?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
  expenseButton:[1,2,3,4,5],
      chosenExpenseId: null
  },
    computed: {
      test() {
        return this.expenseButton.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="yourBalance">
      Your monthly balance
      <br />
      <span>{{ test }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. "expensesValue" is a property inside that array.       2. The array is coming from a parent                                 3. The parent recieves it through a get request                   I made some edits with more info